# cant get virtual env to activate on windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, virtual-environment

I can't get the virtual env to activate on windows for python3. When I type in source virt/Scripts/activate in cmd, it says the term source is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

To activate `virtual env` using `cmd` use the following command:

```
<virtual_folder_name>\Scripts\Activate.bat
```

When you activate the virtual environment your command prompt will change from:

```
C:\Users\Username
```

to

```
(virtual_folder_name) C:\Users\Username
```